# SQL Query support based on language settings in android

Tags: sql, android

Can someone tell me if there is way to write an SQL query to get list
of contact names from phonebook which matches its english name given
that the phone language is set to Spanish.

E.g., If I write a query to get a contacts whose last name ends with
"Dad", but for some contacts the last name "Dad" will be stored as
**"papá"** in **Spanish**.
So the query where I write to match for lastname="dad" will not work
as they are different characters. Is there a way in SQL which takes
care of language translation as well while quering?

Appreicate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could see this working is if you passed in parameters to the SQL search.  Then you take those parameters and run them through some sort of translation service (English --> Spanish) before you passed them to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into putting some Strings into [localized XML files](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). This way, you could just do something like:

```
String dad = getString(R.string.dad);
```

Then just use the `dad` variable to build the SQL query. Have a different strings.xml file for each language (under `res/values-xx/strings.xml`, where "xx" is the two letter language designation), and Android will pull the string automatically depending on the user's language setting.

Comment: This solution again has a limitation.. If I have two different contacts say **Alex's Dad** and **Nguyen papá**. Then it won't find both the contacts from the query.

Comment: True, but if the user's primary language is Spanish, it's unlikely they would use both. Only other alternative I can think of offhand is to just build like a String[] for each (i.e. `dad[] = { dad, papa, ... };`) and build the SQL query with a bunch of OR statements (i.e. `for (String d : dad) { query += "OR " + d };`) or something to that effect.